# Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am implementing 2 screens using react-navigation. But I got the warning below while navigating to the second page:

> Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain Javascript Classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.

Versions:

- react:             16.3.1
- react-native:      0.55.2
- react-navigation:  1.5.11
- util:              0.10.3

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import styles from "./styles";

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;     
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>         
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>                 
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=> navigate('Home')} >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import styles from "./styles";

export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>         
                <Text>Home Screen</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: From the looks of it, there's an old module that you have installed that's probably calling the deprecated `isMounted` method. Try removing them one by one until the warning is gone. My guess is `react-navigation`. Did you try installing the latest version?

Comment: Yes i updated it all 4 modules to latest version but didn't worked for me. Even also tried downgrading too.

Comment: Did you try removing them one by one? Also, do you have any other pages than home.js and login.js?

Comment: No i don't have any other pages, ok let me try render home page without navigation.

Comment: Oh yes seems issue with `onPress={()=> navigate('Home')}` because when render home page default without navigation then warning disappears.

Comment: Okay... Your problem might be connected somehow to the router that you have chosen then. Try using a different one. I personally use `react-native-navigation` by Wix but you can also use `react-native-router-flux` if you don't feel like implementing your navigation natively.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is a problem with latest React Navigation and React Native. To silence it add:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
```

I expect it will be fixed in React Navigation within next few weeks.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no other solution than keep silence this warning ?

Comment: They are claiming it isn't React Navigation causing the issue. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3956

Comment: Where Do I place this code? Didn't worked when I placed it in my App.js component. (using crna cli)

Comment: place it in `index.js`

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18868 from the last comment: the fixes are part of the new 0.56 release candidate.

Comment: While this solution silences the YellowBox message, it doesn't seem to have any effect on silencing the output in the debugger, where the message repeats multiple times a second.

Answer (score 7):

Is is actually a React-Native issue

You can wait and check when a fix is available here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18868

Or in the meantime you can hide the warning like suggested.

Comment: According to that GItHub issue, it has been fixed in react-native v0.57.0

Answer (score 1):

Use this statement in `index.js`:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works for me:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
```

Answer (score 0):

react-navigation issue is now closed, you can look [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3956)

They are stating that it is a problem somewhere inside of react-native

Comment: Yes i looked but fact is warning comes when `navigate('page_name')` called

Answer (score 0):

This is not from `react-navigation` as i looked into the node_modules and `react-navigation` doesn't use `isMounted`, Its coming from somewhere within React-Native, 
I have also done same hack used by @Romsun

```
    import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring this message is the wrong way for a good developer
If we remove this problem then the memory leakage is decreased.

Comment: This answer is very concise, perhaps it should be a comment?  Sometimes more details would be appreciated.  However, thanks, as decreasing memory-leaks is always an important goal.

Comment: @Gajarajan Yes but till we have no other solution.

Comment: We have to keep watch discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18868)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EXPO for RN development then this issue is now fixed in expo 27.0.2.

See https://forums.expo.io/t/warnings-after-upgrade-to-expo-27/9579/12

Comment: Can you please include the part on how to update expo to the latest version in your answer here? (Using blockquotes) That way, future visitors of this page would find the solution quicker. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, this isn't a link-only answer. The answer says it was a bug and it was solved in a later version of Expo. The link is a reference to back that up

Answer (score 0):

The answers above didn't work for me, but adding the following to `index.js` did the trick:

```
console.ignoreYellowBox = ['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated'];
```

Or upgrade to expo `27.0.2` which basically adds the above to `Expo.js`. See more information here: https://forums.expo.io/t/warnings-after-upgrade-to-expo-27/9579/10

As some of the other answers stated, it's a `react-native` issue so hopefully it will be fixed soon there and then in the following version of Expo.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did for this problem for the time being:

step 1:Tap on the warning

step 2: In the yellow window click on the stack trace option in top right

step 3: Find the path where the warning has occured,ex:C:\Users\username\projectname\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js

step 4: Open the path in editor

step 5: Find the key word isMounted under the deprecated api's and delete the deprecated function and warning related under it.

step 6: Save and reload your app!!thats it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an expo client, update your version to expo@27.0.2 which fixes this warning. . .