# How to perfect fix isMounted(...) warnings in react-native not to silence this warning

Tags: react-native, warnings

I am getting this warning:

> `Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.`

**How do I fix the warning? I don't want to hide it like this:**

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module 
RCTImageLoader']);
```

Comment: It is better to provide message as text [instead of an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: Also note that a simple Google search for "react native isMounted site:stackoverflow.com" brought up dozens of similar results. Did you look into these before posting this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain Javascript Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49789150/warning-ismounted-is-deprecated-in-plain-javascript-classes)

Answer (score 2):

All of the comments show you how to *hide* it, but not how to resolve it since the false positive has been fixed in React Native.

I was using the variable name `isMounted` in my React Native code, which was a *custom instance variable* on the class. However, this conflicted with a deprecated variable `isMounted` which is innately on `Component` classes - hence the warning.

To solve this, I simply renamed my `isMounted` variable name to `mounted`.

Comment: Can confirm changing the name solved it : )