# Issue with react-native versions 0.55.4 and 0.56.0

Tags: react-native

When i am using react-native version 0.56.0 i get this error
**Unable to resolve module 'AccessibilityInfo', when trying to create release bundle**
after some search on stack overflow i found https://stackoverflow.com/a/51413785/7903808 suggesting to downgrade to  0.55.4 version.

after downgrading to 0.55.4 i got another error 
**isMounted(...) is deprecated in plain JavaScript React classes. Instead, make sure to clean up subscriptions and pending requests in componentWillUnmount to prevent memory leaks.** on [git issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18868) i found its already fix in the 0.56.0  version.

this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790811/7903808  suggesting that to ignore.

```
 import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
 YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
```

is this  memory leaking issue will make problem in app review?.